# Convert Bearer token to JWT token using .NET 6

Tags: .net, jwt, base64, bearer-token

I have been asked to connect to different applications via API, one application is a third-party app, (vendors) and the other one are. NET.
the only way to authenticate available is via a token. the vendor app allegedly said that I will get a JWT token that we don't see. YES. when we tried to decode it is just a bearer token. I don't understand why.
I need to find the token payload that this vendor app is sending. I need a header payload and signature.
what I get :
I get a bearer token but I need the JWT Token(header payload and signature).
the vendor keeps claiming that they are sending a JWT token, but I am getting a bearer token.
-I tried -

1. https://jwt.io -(NOT AN OPTION )because again what I get is a bearer token.
2. string url = "https://...some URL HERE....";

```
    HttpRequestMessage httpRequest = new HttpRequestMessage();
    httpRequest.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    var credentials = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(url);                                                                                 var auth = httpRequest.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer",Convert.ToBase64String(credentials));
    string authFinal = auth.ToString().Replace("Bearer ", "");
```

[image]

Now, my only option is what?
Im using .NET 6

Comment: I'm not really clear on what your question is (a bearer token can be a JWT, for example), but it looks like this code is splitting a JWT into it's parts and then throwing away everthing but the header. What is in `authFinal2`? Does that look like a JWT?

Comment: Also, please post information in text whenever possible. Then I could just decode that base64 string myself to check its contents.

Comment: @ShauntheSheep thanks for reply , It looks like I was not requesting the specifics of the authorization headers with the right method.  That's why it was giving me a different Bearer token value.  The correct way to call it was:   var jwt =  Request.Headers.Authorization.ToString().Replace("Bearer ", "");    .......This is for .NET 6 ( old versions may use a different class and methods to get the Authorization from headers).